# How to package add ons in Python for software

Tags: python, python-3.x, add-on

I am using a software program that uses Python API, and I would like to build add-ons to be packaged and used with this software program. I am a first year student in software development, so I am new to all of this. How does this work? Are you allowed to do this for any software? Any insights would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on your needs you could go from simply using [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) for importing python files in a folder to using a plugin framework like [pyplugs](https://github.com/gahjelle/pyplugs).

Comment: Thank you for the response! And does using the plugin framework "hide" the code from users? I envision them downloading the package file, then it automatically connecting to the software, or perhaps there is something I am missing to do in between those steps.

Comment: It doesn't hide the code from users. You could maybe put the python files in zip files with your own file extension (e.g. Firefox uses xpi but they are zip files) so the plugin can be associated with your program (so opening the file copies it to your plugins folder). Python can directly import modules from zip files with [zipimport](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipimport.html). But if you really "need" to hide the code just don't use python, that's not the way python is meant to be used and it's much more work than simply using a compiled language.

Comment: I see, and this would only allow the program to open the custom file extension zip file? Users wouldn't be able to? And yes, there are other ways, but this software uses Python API and is what I need to work with.